# recyclerview not displaying sqlite data in fragment

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

Code

```
public class UsageSettings2 extends Fragment {
MainData mDatabaseHelper;
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
UserDataHelper mHelper;
private List<UsageHelper> usage = new ArrayList<>();
private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
private UsageAdapter mAdapter;
SQLiteDatabase db;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_usage2, container, false);

    final MainData myDBHlpr = new MainData(getActivity());
    db = myDBHlpr.getWritableDatabase();

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.usagelist);
        //Add the data first
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        //and then create a object and pass the lis
        mAdapter = new UsageAdapter(usage);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    Cursor csr = myDBHlpr.getAllQuestions2(getActivity());
    while (csr.moveToNext()) {

        String name = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("Name"));
        int sent = csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex("MessagesSent"));
        int recieved = csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex("MessagesRecieved"));
        int total = csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex("Messages"));
        String time = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("TimeSpent"));

        new UsageHelper(name,sent,recieved,total,time);


        int profile_counts = myDBHlpr.getProfilesCount2();
        Log.d("FFF", String.valueOf(profile_counts));


    }



        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Adapter

```
public class UsageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UsageAdapter.UsageViewHolder>{

private List<UsageHelper> mUsageHelper;

public UsageAdapter(List<UsageHelper> UsageAdapter) {
    this.mUsageHelper = UsageAdapter;
}

public class UsageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView mName;
    public TextView mSent;
    public TextView mRecieved;
    public TextView mTotal;
    public TextView mTime;

    public UsageViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        mName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        mSent = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.sent);
        mRecieved = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.recieved);
        mTotal = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.total);
        mTime = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.time);
    }
}

@Override
public UsageAdapter.UsageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View V = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_activity_usage,parent,false);
    return new UsageAdapter.UsageViewHolder(V);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final UsageViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final UsageHelper usageHelper = mUsageHelper.get(position);

    holder.mName.setText(usageHelper.getName());
    holder.mSent.setText(usageHelper.getSent());
    holder.mRecieved.setText(usageHelper.getRecieved());
    holder.mTotal.setText(usageHelper.getTotal());
    holder.mTime.setText(usageHelper.getTime());

}


@Override
public  int getItemCount() {
    return mUsageHelper.size();
}
```

Modal

```
public class UsageHelper {
private String Name;
private int Sent;
private int Recieved;
private int Total;
private String Time;

public UsageHelper() {
}

public UsageHelper(String Name, int Sent ,int Recieved, int Total, String Time) {

    this.Name = Name;
    this.Sent = Sent;
    this.Recieved = Recieved;
    this.Total = Total;
    this.Time = Time;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.Name = name;
}

public int getSent() {
    return Sent;
}

public void setSent(int sent) {
    this.Sent = sent;
}

public int getRecieved() {
    return Recieved;
}

public void setRecieved(int recieved) {
    this.Recieved = recieved;
}

public String getTime() {
    return Time;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    this.Time = time;
}

public int getTotal() {
    return Total;
}

public void setTotal(int total) {
    this.Total = total;
}
```

}

The problem is that its not showing anything... the fragment is blank when i open it although the data is present... Any idea why its now showing any data? Im not getting any error just that the data isnt showing..........................................................................

Got an error after making changes according to answers

Custom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/usage"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/black">

<RelativeLayout
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/mid"
        android:text="Name"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:paddingVertical="10dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingVertical="10dp"
        android:text="Sent"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recieved"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sent"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingVertical="10dp"
        android:text="Recieved"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/total"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/recieved"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingVertical="10dp"
        android:text="Total"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/recieved"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingVertical="10dp"
        android:text="Time \nSpent"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you din't add data from SQLite to your Adapter

Comment: Its complicated @pskink

Comment: new UsageHelper(name,sent,recieved,total,time);
 Doesnt this line add @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: no, it just creates an instance. It does not add anything anywhere. Java is not smart enough to magically understand why yu created that object and how you want to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `usage` list is always empty because you are not adding the new "UsageHelper" you are creating from your Cursor into the list.

What you need to do is the following:

```
Cursor csr = myDBHlpr.getAllQuestions2(getActivity());
while (csr.moveToNext()) {

    ...

    UsageHelper newListItem = new UsageHelper(name,sent,recieved,total,time);
    usage.add(newListItem);

    ...

}
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

When you finish adding elements to the list, you want to notify your adapter that the list has new items, so you have to call to `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` and the new elements will be displayed

Comment: @NikkiZepher post the code of your layout. Are you sure that those TextView with those id exist ?

Comment: Ok my bad i tried to setText an int value... but still doesnt solve the problem... See edit

Comment: in this layout `custom_activity_usage` you should have all the TextView you are using in the ViewHolder with the proper id, if you don't, it will fail. Please upload the code for that layout @NikkiZepher

Answer (score 0):

In the `while` loop of `onCreateView()`, add each row from the db to the list:

```
usage.add(new UsageHelper(name,sent,recieved,total,time));
```

instead of just:

```
new UsageHelper(name,sent,recieved,total,time)
```

which does nothing.
And after the loop finishes:

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

so the RecyclerView loads all the added rows to the list.
**Edit**
Replace

```
holder.mSent.setText(usageHelper.getSent());
```

with

```
holder.mSent.setText("" + usageHelper.getSent());
```

because `usageHelper.getSent()` is `int` and it is treated as a resource id.

Answer (score 0):

add mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); in while condition or after adding your data in model class.

Comment: metch R.id.sent  in xml file